# svn asking to upgrade working copy after updating to MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, svn, macos-sierra

So I upgraded to MacOS Sierra and now whenever I try to do anything in my working copy I get the error that it

"is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.9.4 (r1740329)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first."

When I run svn upgrade, as it suggests it says 
"Can't open file /.svn/entries: No such file or directory"

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that the version of the SVN client got upgraded locally; whereas your local working copy (and the server) didn't change! Now the new client is unable to work with the existing working copy.

Now you have three choices:

1. You can try to get your new SVN client to accept the existing working copy
2. You downgrade your local SVN client to the previous version
3. You throw your existing repositories away and start with fresh checkouts

For option 1, you might look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165001/unable-to-upgrade-svn-working-copy) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992034/svn-upgrade-working-copy).

For option 2, [this](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/install-specific-version-homebrew/) might help.

Option 3; I guess, is the one-line-no-brainer which maybe costs you download time, but should come with the least amount of "you spending your time" debugging this (unless you got a ton of uncommitted changes sitting in your current repositories). But of course, you would **first** try to create a new checkout with the new client, before throwing the old directory away.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! That really helps

Comment: This is one of the worst answers I've ever seen. It looks like legit, but provides tells wrong information.

Comment: @bahrep Feel free to point out the problems in my answer; or to write up your own, better answer. As said; I have been in similar situations; and can say that all of the provided options did work for me at some point. So, where exactly I am so terribly wrong?

Comment: The problem is that there is `Can't open file /.svn/entries` error. It means that this working copy is broken. I don't have any idea how this happened and I see this problem for the very first time.

Comment: @bahrep And you think that creating a new working copy won't fix that?

Comment: OK new working copy will solve that. I downvoted this answer for wrong usage of *working copy* and *repo* terms. However, there is a great chance that other software on OPs machine will break new working copies again.

Comment: So, you are saying: you spent the time to fix my wording; to then downvote? Interesting approach ;-)

Answer (score 12):

1. Open Terminal
2. go to error folder. ex : cd svn/project/game
3. command write only "svn upgrade"

Comment: This solution worked for me.

I was getting

svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '/some/root/directory/subdirectory/mydirectory' as it is not a working copy root, 
the root is '/some/root/directory'

So I did "

cd /some/root/directory
and "
svn upgrade
"
It was working. Thanks for this

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by doing the 'svn upgrade' on the 'cd' of root folder of the project